# How to process large size satellite images without loading the entire image into the memory?

Tags: visualisation, rendering

I am working with large size satellite images having size around 25 GB. My system is having 8 GB of RAM and gets entirely freezed after reading the image. What is the efficient way to process images having size more than the system RAM?

Comment: Please edit your question and specify what software you use.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works.

Comment: You used tag "visualisation" but also wrote about processing. Which one is your main aim?

Comment: For most purposes, only a tiny portion of the file is kept in memory (usually the header metadata and read and decompression buffers). Sometimes the OS will cache recently read pages, but only with otherwise unused memory. If you have explicitly told an application to read a raster to RAM on a system with less RAM  than the file size, it might first try to exhaust swap (which is one to ten *thousand* times slower than RAM). In general, the solution is, "Don't do that."